# Media recorder stops in an invalid state

Tags: android, mobile, mediarecorder

I'm attempting to create a simple app that records audio. I'm using the standard [MediaRecorder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder) to achieve that. Here is what I have so far:

1. I'm successfully starting the mediaRecorder using this method

   ```
   public void startRecording(String filePath) throws IOException {

   String state = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState();
   if (!state.equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
       throw new IOException("SD Card is not mounted.  It is " + state + ".");
   }

   // make sure the directory we plan to store the recording in exists
   File directory = new File(filePath).getParentFile();
   if (!directory.exists() && !directory.mkdirs()) {
       throw new IOException("Path to file could not be created.");
   }

   recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC );

   recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
   recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
   recorder.setOutputFile(filePath);

   recorder.setOnErrorListener(errorListener);
   recorder.setOnInfoListener(infoListener);

   try {
       recorder.prepare();

   } catch (Exception e) {
       Timber.e("Error while prepareing media recorder " + e.getMessage());
   }

   try {

       recorder.start();
       SharedPrefs.setIsRecording(true);
       Timber.d("Started to record " + SharedPrefs.isRecording());

   } catch (Exception e) {
       Timber.e("Error while starting the media recorder " + e.getMessage());
   } }
   ```

this works fine and I can see locally that the file is created in the specified folder.

2. Now this is what I use to stop recording:

   ```
   public void stopRecording() {

   if (recorder == null) {
           Timber.e("recorder is null");
       }

   if (SharedPrefs.isRecording()) {

       try {
           recorder.stop();

       } catch (Exception r) {
           Timber.e("Error while attempting to stop " + r.getMessage());
       }

       try {
           recorder.release();

       } catch (Exception e) {
           Timber.e("Error while attempting to release " + e.getMessage());
       }

       Timber.e("We stopped recording");
       SharedPrefs.setIsRecording(false);

   } else {
       Timber.e("Attempting to stop recording while not recording ");
   } }
   ```

   Now when stopRecording() is being called this is the error message that I get:

   ```
    E/MediaRecorder: stop called in an invalid state:1
   ```

   AudioRecorder: Error while attempting to stop null

Note: When I locally go to the folder where the file is and I refresh it, I can see the size of the file is incrementing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you check that `recorder` is not null while stopping it?

Comment: Hi @TDG! Yes, mediaRecorder obj is not  null when attempting to stop. (see updated code)